# Data table join multiple tables in a single join

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to link a number of tables together in a single join statement. i.e. `table a` joins to `table b` joins to `table c`.

```
# create some tables
a = data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4),amount = c(2,2,3,4))
b = data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4), id2=c(1,1,2,2), multiplier = c(4,5,6,7))
c = data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4))
d = data.table(id2=c(1,2), amount = c(2,20))
```

Next I can join table `c` to both `a` and `b`

```
c[b, on = .(id), `:=` (multiplier = i.multiplier, m2 = multiplier*am)][a, on = .(multiplier==id), am := i.amount]
```

> ```
>    id multiplier am m2
> 1:  1          4  4 16
> 2:  2          5 NA NA
> 3:  3          6 NA NA
> 4:  4          7 NA NA
> ```

**How can I join table `b` to `d` and then `c` to `b`?**

The following is not working:

```
c[b, on = .(id), `:=` (multiplier = i.multiplier, m2 = multiplier*am)][d, on = .(id2==id2), am := i.amount]

c[b, on = .(id), `:=` (multiplier = i.multiplier, m2 = multiplier*prod(b[d, on = .(id2), amount])]
```

Comment: there is a pending https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/599 for that

Answer (score 0):

I got things the wrong way round:

```
c[, m2 := b[, by=id, multiplier*prod(d[.SD, on =.(id2), amount])]$V1]
```